# Center of a bimodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, representation-theory, bimodules

If we have a $\mathbb{k}$-algebra $R$ over a field $\mathbb{k}$ together with an $R$-bimodule $M$ we can consider the center $Z(M)=\{m\in M \vert \ \ rm=mr \ \ \forall r\in R\}.$ This is again an $R$-bimodule. If we consider $R$ as the regular bimodule, then $Z(R)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R-R}(R,R)$ as $\mathbb{k}$-algebras. Can we describe $Z(M)$ similarly? Is $Z(M)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R-R}(M,M)$ as $R$-bimodules? Can $Z(M)$ be described in more categorical terms?

Comment: Have you considered $\mathrm{Hom}_{R-R}(R,M)$?

Comment: @AndrewHubery But wouldn't this imply that the center is functorial, which it isn't?

Comment: The centre of a _ring_ is not functorial, so $R\to S$ doesn’t induce $Z(R)\to Z(S)$, but if $f:M\to N$ is an $R$-bimodule map, then it does induce a map $Z(M)\to Z(N)$.

Comment: More generally, a map $f:M\to N$ of $R$-bimodules induces a functor $HH^*(f):HH^*(R,M)\to HH^*(R,N)$ on Hochschild cohomology.

Comment: The center is not necessarily an $R$-bimodule; it is a $Z(R)$-bimodule.  To see this, let $M=R$ for a noncommutative ring $R$.  Then $1$ is in the center but not every multiple of $1$ is in the center.